# Unable to query orderItem with an ID

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

when I tried to query an **orderItem** using its id, I am getting a message saying:

> "orderItem object not found for the provided id".

But the same **orderItemId** is associated with a billing Item. Here is the query I tried.

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Billing_Order_Item/172219719/getObject.json?objectMask=mask[order[userRecord[id,username]]]
```

The orderItemId in the above rest call is associated to a billingItemId: "**144975043**".

Also when I tried pulling [SoftLayer_Account::getNextInvoiceTopLevelBillingItems](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getNextInvoiceTopLevelBillingItems), some billing items are associated to respective **orderItem** but some are not, I would like to know what would be the reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am affraid that the information that you provided in your question is not enough to help you, I can get successfully the billing order item your issue may be due to your API user does not have enough permissions so I recomend you to try the same request using the master account in order to see if the issue is reproduccible.

In regards to some associated billing items the issue may be the same (permissions), because I also can see all the billing items associated are being displayed (Just in case the SoftLayer_Account::getNextInvoiceTopLevelBillingItems displays the Top billing item associated to your device,so you only will see a billing item to see the rest of billing items associated to the device you need to use a mask to displays the children e.g. objectMask=mask[children], however it could generates a lot data and you may get errors in the query due to timeout and you would need to use result limits ).

So please try with the master user if you are getting the same error let me know what billing items are not being displayed.

Regards

Comment: Yes that's correct. with master user credentials, i am able to pull all the required data.